# Не хотим js в ответах

Tags: обсуждение, метки

В большинстве вопросов наличие тегов [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) и [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) понимается как то, что вопрос по веб-разработке и можно заодно при необходимости использовать [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). В большинстве случаев это правильно, однако иногда это не так. Вполне возможно, что спрашивающий сам знает, как сделать нечто при помощи джаваскрипта, но его интересует именно чистое решение на html+css. Некоторое время назад я пытался добавить метку [nojs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nojs), но @Discord выпилил её как мета-метку. На мой взгляд, эта метка всё-таки должна быть, чтобы явно показать, что решения с использованием скриптов его не интересуют.

- Мой вопрос, где пришлось явно обозначить желание увидеть ответ без js:
  [Проверить наличие переполнения блока на css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420097/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css)
- Вопрос c войной правок из-за неясности намерений автора:
  [Правила для определения четных/нечетных с игнорированием определенных блоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463002/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)
- Вопросы, где метку [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) не указывают, хотя никаких возражений против его использования не имеют, искать лень, но их полно.

Answer (score 5):

Нет, такая метка не нужна.

В таком случае придётся дополнительно прописывать условия в вопросе :(

Comment: Я считаю, что если человек хочет пользоваться технологиями X и Y, и никак не Z, то это должно быть выделено в вопросе. Если не выделено, то нужно либо уточнять у ТС, либо отвечать разными способами. А ещё можно после принятия правильного решения, отредактировать вопрос и привести его в более удобное для поиска вида. Для ТС всё ясно. А вот из поисковика может прийти человек, которому нужен ответ не тот, который выбрал ТС. Чтобы он нашёл этот вопрос, мы должно позаботиться о тегах.

Comment: @LEQADA, "человек хочет пользоваться технологиями X и Y, и никак не Z, то это должно быть выделено в вопросе" - как правило, для этого служат метки. Никто же не будет говорить "мне нужно решение на C#, но никак не на паскале" - это очевидно из меток. Но к связке html+css+js отношение другое и метки по умолчанию рассматриваются всем комплектом, а не только те, которые поставлены в вопросе.

Comment: @LEQADA, "_А ещё можно после принятия правильного решения, отредактировать вопрос..._" метки должны характеризовать _вопрос_ а не ответ. Если мы будем подгонять вопросы под ответы (выставляя правильные метки), то все может закончится весьма плачевно.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, если принятый ответ использует нечто, о чём забыли упомянуть в вопросе - то это именно забыли - не зря же он принятый. А вот если он не принят, то подгонять вопрос, скорее всего, не стоит. Хотя про старые заброшенные вопросы где-то было отдельное обсуждение на эту тему.

Comment: Создать метку [php-не-нужен] и ставить на вопросы по php.

Answer (score 0):

Да, такая метка нужна.

Дополнительно голосуем за комментарий с желаемым написанием.
Можно предлагать свои варианты тега.

Comment: [tag:nojs]​​​​​

Comment: [tag:no-js]​​​​

Comment: [tag:без-javascript]

Comment: Я думаю, без дополнительного комментария в вопросе метка `nojs` или `no-js` будет всё равно непонятна большинству. То есть всё равно придётся писать: "не хочу js". Вариант `без-javascript` понятней, но какой-то некрасивый из-за смеси русского и английского.

Comment: Не вызовет ли метка `nojs` ассоциацию с `nosql` и, таким образом, не добавит ли путаницу? Некоторые могут подумать: это новая технология "not only javascript".

Comment: [tag:без-скриптов]

Comment: [tag:без-использования-скриптов] @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Вот без смеси языков и даже в рифму: [tag:без-джыэс]